# HTML footer responsive not aligning perfectly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive website. Everything looks great except for the footer when in mobile view the content dont seem to align perfectly.
Here are screenshots.

**This is the desktop view**

[image]

**This is the mobile view**

[image]

As you can see everything is messed up. Here's my code

```
<div id="footer" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
                    <p id="color"> Supported By </p>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
                    <a href="http://www.kafd.jo/" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="Images/King-Abdullah-Fund-Development-Jordan-360-Panorma-Video.png" id="imageclass1"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
                    <a href="http://visitjordan.com/" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="Images/Jordan-Tourism-Board-Visit-Jordan-Lolo.png" id="imageclass1"></a>
                </div>

                <div class="navbar-text" id="centered">
                    <a href="http://www.360mea.com/request-a-recording/" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="Images/Request-a-Recording-Jordan-360-Panorama.png" id="imagecenter"></a>
                </div>

                <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
                    <a href="http://www.oasis500.com/" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="Images/Oasis-500-logo-360.png" id="imageclass"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
                    <a href="http://www.ayla.com.jo/" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="Images/Ayla-Logo.png" id="imageclass1"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
                    <a href="http://www.manaseergroup.com/" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="Images/Manaser.png" id="imageclass2"></a>
                </div> 
                <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
                    <p id="color">Partners</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And for the CSS

```
#centered {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    left: 40%;
}
#imagecenter{
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
#imageclass1{
    max-width: 90px;
    max-height: 90px;
}
#imageclass2{
    max-width: 70px;
    max-height: 60px;
}
```

And here's my attempt on mobile view

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    body {
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .img-responsive {
        position:relative;
        max-width: 20%;
    }
    #color{
        font-size: 5px;
    }
    #footer{
        max-height: 200px;
    }
}
```

If there's an easier approach than the way I did it, I would be very thankful.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget the pull-left pull-right on each element and use col's layout (col offset will be helpfull for the centered one).

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap provides easy ways for designing responsive sites. You just add classes to your divs and bootstrap's css will do the job! You can find it here:
http://getbootstrap.com/